# How can I count to a number in python 3.4.3?

Tags: count

So I need to create a program that counts to a number and then stops.

So say I select the number to be 4, the code I want needs to print:
One
Two
Three
Four

Or if I need it to be 5, it will go:
One
Two
Three
Four

Comment: you can post your code that will be useful to aid us for dealing with your question

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing the question and adding a language tag.